# How to find $P(X<Y)$ where $X$ and $Y$ are random variables?

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, density-function

I'm trying to understand this proof in this [book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1138369918) page 319:

[image]

My question is why $f_{T_1,T_2}(t_1,t_2)$ is the circled area above? in fact, my question is more general. I'm having troubles to understand $P(X<Y)$ where $X$ and $Y$ are random variables. What I know if $P(X<x)$. I'm very confused, please help.

Comment: Do you understand the phrase "integrate the joint PDF of $T_1$ and $T_2$" in the first sentence of the solution? Have you learned how to obtain the joint PDF of two independent variables? (Presumably it's explained in that book somewhere before page 319.)

Comment: @DavidK what I learned was knowing the joint PDF then we can multiply to obtain the marginal PDFs.

Comment: @DavidK Do you understand the phrase "integrate the joint PDF of $_1$ and $_2$" No, I didn't find this definition in the book

Comment: It's the other way around: you take the marginal PDF of each variable and multiply them together, and the result is the joint PDF. This is only if the variables are independent.

Comment: The joint PDF is the PDF of the random vector $(T_1,T_2)$. "Morally" it assigns to each point $(x,y)$ the "mass" of that point, i.e. the "probability" that $(T_1,T_2)$ is equal to $(x,y)$. (More formally, the PDF $f_{(T_1,T_2)}$ satisfies $\mathsf P((T_1,T_2)\in A)=\int_{A} f_{(T_1,T_2)}(x,y)\,\mathrm d(x,y)$ for all measurable $A\subset\mathbb R^2$.) The book is interested in the set $A=\{(t_1,t_2)\in\mathbb R^2 : t_1<t_2\}$.

Answer (score 2):

The joint PDF is the PDF of the random vector $(T_1,T_2)$.

"Morally" it assigns to each point $(x,y)$ the "mass" of that point, i.e. the "probability" that $(T_1,T_2)$ is equal to $(x,y)$.

The precise formulation of this fact is that the PDF $f_{(T_1,T_2)}$ satisfies $$\mathsf P((T_1,T_2)\in A)=\int_{A} f_{(T_1,T_2)}(x,y)\,\mathrm d(x,y)$$ for all measurable $A\subset\mathbb R^2$. We are interested in the set $A=\{(t_1,t_2)\in\mathbb R^2 : t_1<t_2\}$, because with that choice, $T_1<T_2$ if and only if $(T_1,T_2)\in A$. So the book computes

$$\int_{A} f_{(T_1,T_2)}(t_1,t_2)\,\mathrm dt_1\,\mathrm d t_2.$$

Answer (score 1):

Whenever two random variable are independent , their joint density is simply the product of their marginal densities .
Here X and Y are independent . So

f(x,y) =f(x) * f(y)

Now .
P(X<Y) = P(X<y| Y=y)

Now for X we need to integrate from 0 to y ....but Y
Can take any value from 0 to infinity .....So need to integrate over the whole range of Y .